# Extract text between two words from all files in a folder in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a folder with many .txt files. I want to read all the files and then extract text from each file located between two words and store them in a .csv file.

Text to be extracted is always between two words

```
IMPRESSION:  "text to be extracted"  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt)

OR

IMPRESSION : "text to be extracted"  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt)
```

The code i wrote below is not extracting text from all files. How do i solve this?

```
    names <- list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\data\\data",
     pattern = "*.txt", all.files = FALSE,
               full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE,
               ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)

    all.names <- lapply(names,readFn)

    readFn <- function(i)
   {

    file <- read_file(i)

    file <- gsub("[\r\n\t]", " ", file)

    extracted_txt <- rm_between(file, 
    'IMPRESSION :', '(Dr. Deepak Bhatt)', 
    extract=TRUE, trim = TRUE, clean = TRUE)

    if(is.na(extracted_txt))
    {
    extracted_txt <- rm_between(file, 
    'IMPRESSION:', '(Dr. Deepak Bhatt)', 
    extract=TRUE, trim = TRUE, clean = TRUE)
    }

    }


    output <- do.call(rbind,all.names)
    name_of_file <- sub(".txt","",names)
    final_output <- cbind(name_of_file,output)
    colnames(final_output) <- c('filename','text')
    write.csv(final_output,"final_output.csv",row.names=F)
```

EXAMPLE 1: filename  = 15-1-2011.txt

```
The optic nerve is normal.


There is diffuse enlargement of the lacrimal gland (more marked on the left side).

IMPRESSION:

Bilateral diffuse irregular enlargement of the lacrimal gland is due to inflammatory enlargement (? Sjogerns syndrome).
The left gland is more enlarged than right.
No mass lesion or cystic lesion noted.
No evidence of retinal detachment.


(Dr. Deepak Bhatt)

(B-Scan findings are interpretation of echoes and need to be correlated clinically)
```

#

EXAMPLE 2: 1-12-48.txt

```
The ciliary body and ciliary process are normal in position and texture.

There is marked steching of the zonules.


IMPRESSION :

Left sided marked stretching of the zonules noted from 2 to 6 O’clock position.
There is absence of zonules at 3 O’clock position.
The angle is normal and the ciliary body, processes are normal in position.


(Dr. Deepak Bhatt)

(UBM findings are interpretation of echoes and need to be correlated clinically)
```

#### objective

```
OUTPUT file: final_output.csv

15-1-2011      Bilateral diffuse.....retinal detachment.

1-12-48        Left sided marked stretching of the zonules ...in  position.
```

Comment: Will there be "(" within text to extract?

Comment: yes in example 1 it is there. but not in all files

Comment: Try to find pattern, where to START is easy: find row number with "IMPRESSION", find END row number with "Dr" is easy if "text to be extracted" doesn't start with "(". Once we know these, readLines, get rows we want, remove new lines `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` for that:

```
text_between_words <- "IMPRESSION:  text to be extracted  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt)"
gsub('IMPRESSION:\\s+(.*)\\s+\\(.*\\)', '\\1', text_between_words)
```

The result:

```
[1] "text to be extracted "
```

Or in combination with `trimws`:

```
trimws(gsub('IMPRESSION:(.*)\\(.*\\)', '\\1', text_between_words))
```

The result of that:

```
[1] "text to be extracted"
```

When there is sometimes a space between `IMPRESSION` and `:`, then you can adapt the code to:

```
text_between_words2 <- "IMPRESSION :  text to be extracted  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt)"
trimws(gsub('IMPRESSION\\s{0,1}:(.*)\\(.*\\)', '\\1', text_between_words2))
```

As you can see, I added `\\s{0,1}` between `IMPRESSION` and `:`. This will look whether there are zero or one spaces between `IMPRESSION` and `:`. The result of that:

```
[1] "text to be extracted"
```

For the adaptations as requested in the comment below, you need to adapt the approach too:

```
text_between_words3 <- "Some Text before..... IMPRESSION: text to be extracted (Dr. Deepak Bhatt) text that should go too"
trimws(gsub('.*IMPRESSION\\s{0,1}:(.*)\\(.*\\).*', '\\1', text_between_words3))
```

The result:

```
[1] "text to be extracted"
```

If it is only that specific name (`Dr. Deepak Bhatt`) in the text, you can also do:

```
trimws(gsub('.*IMPRESSION\\s{0,1}:(.*)\\(Dr. Deepak Bhatt\\).*', '\\1', text_between_words3))
```

Comment: yes but sometimes the text is between IMPRESSION : and (Dr. Deepak Bhatt). i.e. A extra space between IMPRESSION and the colon

Comment: @pranavnerurkar I have adapted my answer. I hope it solves your problem now.

Comment: your answer works only for the example you have given. What to do to make it work for following case:  text_between_words <- "Some Text before..... IMPRESSION:  text to be extracted  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt) ..... some text after"

Comment: @pranavnerurkar then you need to add `.*` before `IMPRESSION` like this: `trimws(gsub('.*IMPRESSION\\s{0,1}:(.*)\\(.*\\)', '\\1', text_between_words))`

Comment: Now your answer removes text before IMPRESSION but there is text even after  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt) that also should go.

Comment: You might want to give a little more data, rather than keeping us guessing.  --  Only `R`? This looks like a perfect `awk` job...

Comment: @vaettchen I don't know `awk`, maybe you can post an `awk` answer?

Comment: i have added examples. hope your answer works for them. i will test and see

Comment: i am getting "text to be extracted  (Dr. Deepak Bhatt)" instead of "text to be extracted" for the examples